# Hyperlink not responding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I added a simple hyperlink inside a javascript function. It looks below:

```
if (!root.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '')) {
                var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://");

                root.innerHTML =
                    '<h2>Your browser is not compatible with FlexPaper</h2>' +
                        '<h3>Upgrade to a newer browser or download Adobe Flash Player 10 or higher.</h3>' +
                        '<p>Click on the icon below to download the latest version of Adobe Flash</p> ' +
                        '<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer" >Enable Flash</a>';
```

When I run it, my web browser displays everything correctly.The only issue is when I tried to click on the hyperlink, I get no respond. I have been researching for the past hour trying to figure out why. The code above is writen in a `.js` file and I tried implementing the hyperlink in a `.jsp` file inside a HTML tag and it works fine.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that [your browser is blocking the link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188870/what-makes-an-unsafe-script-unsafe/31189927)

I just ran your code below and it works fine for me so it may be a security issue.

```js
function initialise(){
 dd = document.getElementById('div_location') 
 dd.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '')
                 var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://");

                 dd.innerHTML =
                     '<h2>Your browser is not compatible with FlexPaper</h2>' +
                         '<h3>Upgrade to a newer browser or download Adobe Flash Player 10 or higher.</h3>' +
                         '<p>Click on the icon below to download the latest version of Adobe Flash ' +
                         '<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer" >Enable Flash</a>';
                     
 
}
initialise();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #4c4c4a;
                color: #dbdb67;
            }
            input {
                background-color: #6d6d68;
                color: #dbdb67;
            }

        </style>
        <title>html replace</title>
       

        
    </head>

    <body>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id='div_location'>Let's try making a promise</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean blocking my link?

Comment: I went through the link you sent, doesn't solve my issue. I could click the hyperlink if it's in a HTML tag

Comment: I see.. check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/482gbdy7/. The link get's blocked by the browser. You can see by clicking the shield.

Comment: That's interesting. When you click on the link, a pop up asking "Allow" on the left shows right?

Comment: I ran the jsfiddle and if I click a second time and so on, it doesn't respond anymore. This is weird behaviour.

Comment: Looks like that is actually just a jsfiddle thing:
`(index):381 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/'.
    at https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/:381:22`

Comment: I did managed to make it work IF it's placed inside the jsp file